# Php imprime nombre de constante

Tags: php, constantes

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que desde php estoy creando una constante que tiene la url base de mi página web, la cual este definida asi:

```
<?php

define('base_url', 'localhost/url_de_mi_proyecto/');

?>
```

Y cuando quiero mostrarla, haciendo de esta forma o de cualquier otra forma posible:

```
echo base_url
```

Me imprime literalmente `base_url`, alguien me puede decir porque pasa esto y como lo puedo solucionar por favor. desde ya gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo modificar la configuración de tu servidor de desarrollo (local) para mostrar todos los errores, estableciendo en `php.ini` los valores `display_errors = On` y `error_reporting = E_ALL` con lo que podrás ver cualquier mensaje, error, excepción, advertencia, etc. y sabrás qué es lo que está pasando con la constante. Por cierto, después de modificar la configuración debes reiniciar el servidor (Apache u otro)

Comment: Asegúrate de que la instrucción que define la constante se ejecuta antes que el echo, porque yo diría que no es así. Cuando intentas usar una constante no definida, PHP toma como valor su nombre, y lo reporta en el registro de errores, puedes consultar éste o activar como dice @Triby los errores en pantalla. Ah, y no estaría mal que la constante la definieras en mayúsculas BASE_URL, que es como se suele hacer.